# hiding javascript code or get it outside root folder?

Tags: javascript, apache, hide, root

I am developing an application and have some important information inside the code like IPs and stuff which has to be private. I use apache web server as a server and wanna know if there is any way hide a javascript code or moving it outside root folder ?

Comment: Once the JavaScript gets to the web browser, it's completely visible to the user.

Comment: Ultimate the best you can do is obfuscate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by definition.  Javascript code is run on the *client's* computer.  That means that the client must have access to the Javascript source for it to work.  You could use AJAX to hide certain data until it is needed, but even then the client (and any user with Firebug) would be able to view it.

Comment: The one thing you can do is "munge" the code.  This is where you replace meaningful variables like "theObject" with "a".  This makes your JS files slightly smaller, and much more difficult to read.  Munging is usually done as part of compression; both YUI Compressor, Google's Closure compressor, and many other compressors can do this for you (and if you "view source" on google.com and look at their JS files, you can see an example of compression/munging).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "hide" it would be through some sort of obfuscation utility or to minify the javascript. But, unfortunately, once the javascript code makes it to the browser. There is not much you can do about it.